# SVN pushing changes

Tags: svn

I am used to Git and am learning SVN now.  In Git you have to add the files, commit the changes, and the push to the repo.  In SVN I only found add and commit commands.  Does this mean that when you run `svn commit` the changes are pushed to the server?  If not what command do I run to push changes to a repo?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Correct, `svn commit` will push your local modifications to the server.  Take a look at the [Basic Work Cycle](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html) to get a quick-ish overview of the commands you'll typically use.

The "common" pattern is:

1. `update` to merge the latest changes from the server into your working copy;
2. Perform whatever modifications you need to do;
3. `update` again to make sure you're up to date (you can skip this and the next step will fail if you're not up to date);
4. `commit` to push your changes to the server.

SVN doesn't have a staging area; there's just your working copy and the repository (plus your local pristine, but you only interact with that indirectly when you `revert` any working copy changes).

As a side note, Git and SVN have an awful set of terminology that can overlap when not expected (see `revert` and `checkout`).  Check out [this resource](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html) for some help with that.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else who hit's this thread. If your commit message uses single quotes, it will fail silently, e.g.

```
svn commit -m 'commit message'
```

will not error but will not do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

svn ci -m "Commit Message" : This also work for pushing your changes